# I try upload the user comment into my db. After I click submit, everything looks fine but I look in my db, there are no record.

Tags: php, html, mysql, upload

I tried the tutorial from some website.

I try upload the user comment into my db. After I click submit, everything looks fine but I look in my db, there are no record.

this is the php code

```
$dbhost = 'localhost:8090';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = 'password';
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
if( $_POST ){
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","password");
}
if(!$con){ die('Could not find db');}

mysql_select_db("doctorapp", $con);

$ticket_user_fname = $_POST['fname'];
$ticket_user_lname = $_POST['lname'];
$ticket_email =$_POST['email'];
$ticket_hp =$_POST['contact_number'];
$ticket_content = $_POST['content'];
$ticket_category = $_POST['category'];

$query =" INSERT INTO `ticketing`(`ticket_id`, `fname`, `email`, `content`, `category`, `contact_number`, `lname`) 
VALUES ('ticket_id','ticket_time','ticket_user_fname','ticket_email','ticket_conetnt','ticket_category','ticket_hp','ticket_lname') ";

mysql_query($query);

echo "<h3>We will rreply you as soon as possible. Thank You.</h3>";

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

I am new for php. thank you!

Comment: What Gautam3165 said + ther's no ``$ticket_id`` in your code. Also ``ticket_time`` is at random position where's you require second parameter to be fname.

Comment: Use mysqli or PDO extension mysql is deprecated now.

Comment: How the Hell `VALUES ('ticket_id'` ?? How Ticket Id can be TEXT field ?? It Must be Number(integer)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

May be you forgot to put `$` before variable

```
$query =" INSERT INTO `ticketing`(`ticket_id`, `fname`, `email`, `content`, `category`, `contact_number`, `lname`) 
          VALUES 
          ('$ticket_id','$ticket_time','$ticket_user_fname','$ticket_email','$ticket_content',
           '$ticket_category','$ticket_hp','$ticket_user_lname') ";
```

Make sure that you also defined `$ticket_id` and `$ticket_time` before using them and if the `ticket_id` is the primary key of the table then it would be auto increment for the Uniqueness  and you don't need to insert it seperately.

Comment: Tq. my mistake. And my localhost port is wrong also, now everything is work! tq.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$dbhost = 'localhost:8090';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = 'password';
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die('Could not find db');;

mysql_select_db("doctorapp", $con);

$ticket_user_fname = $_POST['fname'];
$ticket_user_lname = $_POST['lname'];
$ticket_email =$_POST['email'];
$ticket_hp =$_POST['contact_number'];
$ticket_content = $_POST['content'];
$ticket_category = $_POST['category'];

$query =" INSERT INTO `ticketing`(`ticket_id`, `fname`, `email`, `content`, `category`, `contact_number`, `lname`) 
VALUES ('$ticket_id','$ticket_time','$ticket_user_fname','$ticket_email','$ticket_conetnt','$ticket_category','$ticket_hp','$ticket_lname') ";

if(mysql_query($query, $conn)){
  echo "<h3>We will rreply you as soon as possible. Thank You.</h3>";
}

?>
```

you forgot the $ in the insert record